# Swift 3 - View moves up after leaving app and coming back & can't scroll to top

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a scrollview with a bunch of icons in a collection view bring brought in from another screen. If I share one of the icons to anywhere (messenger for example) then I cancel and go back to the app, but then the entire view has moved up and no longer scrolls to the top.

Any ideas?

Normal view:

[image: Normal view]

Sharing the image:

[image]

Come back to app, the collection view has moved up and I cannot scroll to the top.

[image]

Please note that there are constraints in the storyboard and it is working fine in the simulator.

Comment: I have similar problem but my collection view is moving down.... Do you have a custom transition to present the view controller?

Comment: @Yitschak No, it is just a standard transition